# Variable assignment convention in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

In bash script it seems to not allow a space on either side of the `=` sign. For example:

```sh
# bad
a= "ok"
# bad
a ="ok"
# bad
a = "ok"
# good
a="ok"
```

Is this the same across all `shell` languages, or bash-specific? Out of curiosity, why does it not allow a space next to the assignment operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For specific shells, you'll need to look up the documentation for that shell. For `bash`, it's a requirement that there be no spaces in that form (note that there are no spaces on either side of the `=`):

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]`.

*One* reason why this may be the case is that you can use command-temporal assignments where a variable is set only for the duration of a command:

```
pax:~> x=314159 ; echo $x
314159
pax:~> x=42 bash -c 'echo $x'
42
pax:~> echo $x
314159
```

Allowing spaces in the assignment would make it a little difficult to figure out where the assignment finished and where the command started. For example:

```
x= echo echo hello
```

Should this set `x` to `echo` then run `echo hello` or should it set `x` to `""` and then run `echo echo hello`?

If you *want* your assignment to be nicely formatted with spaces, you can use the `((...))` arithmetic evaluation:

```
pax:~> (( val = 117 / 3 )) ; echo $val
39
```

Comment: thanks is `((...))` a standard posix thing or is that specific for bash ?

Comment: `"Fo"` -> `"For"` 1st word 1st paragraph.

Comment: @David542, POSIX shell is a subset of Korn and, from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/, looks to also handle the `((..))` construct as an extension.